# How to use "nvm use" in bin/setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nvm

I am trying to write a setup script for ruby:

```
# path to your application root.
APP_ROOT = Pathname.new File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__)

def system!(*args)
  system(*args) || abort("\n== Command #{args} failed ==")
end

chdir APP_ROOT do
  # This script is a starting point to setup your application.
  # Add necessary setup steps to this file.

  puts '== Installing dependencies =='
  system! 'gem install bundler --conservative'
  system! 'gem install foreman'
  system('bundle check') || system!('bundle install')
  system!('npm install')
  system!('nvm use')
end
```

The last step of "nvm use" always aborts with command failed even though it works fine when I use it outside of the script. What is going on here?

Comment: Does it show something more than `command failed`? backtrace or something?